# Primefaces customize rowEditor with theme icon

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, roweditor

i would like to customize the `p:rowEditor` icons (pencil, etc.) with those provided by any Primefaces theme like Sentinel (see here: [https://www.primefaces.org/eos/sentinel/font-icons.xhtml][1])

I edited my custom CSS file and I tried to overwrite row editor classes copying CSS elements used into Sentinel theme CSS file, so the result is the following :

```
.ui-datatable table tbody tr td .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil
{
  background: none !important;
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;

  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: .2em;
  text-align: center;
  /* opacity: .8; */

  /* For safety - reset parent styles, that can break glyph codes*/
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;

  /* fix buttons height, for twitter bootstrap */
  line-height: 1em;

  /* Animation center compensation - margins should be symmetric */
  /* remove if not needed */
  margin-left: .2em;
}

.ui-datatable table tbody tr td .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil:before {
    content: '\e851';
}
```

No chance to get it working. I see all blank. Maybe do i need to adjust any position attribute?
Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the `text-indent` property is the reason for not showing the content.

`components.css` defines:

```
.ui-icon{
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

To override it, add `text-indent: 0;` to your css for `.ui-icon-pencil`.